# get pair-elements from nested lists of increasing size

Tags: python, list, nested, nlp, corpus

It might be that i am trying to work with data structures that dont fit my need, however...given this:

```
import itertools

listOfFileData = [['[', 'Emma', 'by', 'Jane', 'Austen'] ,['[', 'Persuasion', 'by', 'Jane', 'Austen'] ,['[', 'Sense', 'and', 'Sensibility', 'by'] ,
['[', 'The', 'King', 'James', 'Bible'] ,['[', 'Poems', 'by', 'William', 'Blake'] ,['[', 'Stories', 'to', 'Tell', 'to'] ,
['[', 'The', 'Adventures', 'of', 'Buster'] ,['[', 'Alice', "'", 's', 'Adventures'] ,
['[', 'The', 'Ball', 'and', 'The'] ,['[', 'The', 'Wisdom', 'of', 'Father'] ,['[', 'The', 'Man', 'Who', 'Was'] ,
['[', 'The', 'Parent', "'", 's'] ,['[', 'Moby', 'Dick', 'by', 'Herman'] ,['[', 'Paradise', 'Lost', 'by', 'John'] ,
['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Julius'] ,['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Hamlet'] ,['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Macbeth'] ,
['[', 'Leaves', 'of', 'Grass', 'by'] ]

#print(len(listOfFileData)) # should show 18 files, each is a list of tokens. 

filesDataPairsList = list(itertools.combinations(listOfFileData, 2)) # requires itertools library file(s)

filesDataPairsListTesting = []
for i in range(2,19,2): # 2,4,6,8,...18
    combinationOfPairsList = list(itertools.combinations(listOfFileData[:i], 2)) # make a list, of increasingly sized pairs
    filesDataPairsListTesting.append(combinationOfPairsList)

#print(len(filesDataPairsListTesting)) # should have 9 lists
#print(len(filesDataPairsListTesting[8])) # should have 153 pairs
```

How do i get to each pair, within a loop? I've been working around something like the following. But i'm not getting there.

```
for permutations in filesDataPairsListTesting:
#     print(len(permutations)) # if uncommented should read, 1,6,15,28....153
    for numOfPairs in range(len(permutations)):
        for pair in permutations:
            permutations[0]
            permutations[1]
```

I would like to access each list pair [[],[]], with the intention of being able to process each of the documents from each pair within the for block.

So with element 0 in my filesDataPairsListTesting list. I could just get to each item easily, as

```
        permutations[0]
        permutations[1]
```

But the 2nd element then has 6 pairs... ? So i have to iterate through element 1 6 times, (how?) so that i can get to permutations[0], permutations[1]. It's this part that is throwing me.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you would like us to help, please create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is right now, I can't run your code and it is too hard to figure out what it is supposed to do

Comment: Apologies. I thought i had. Edited to improve code formatting and bring in any requ libraries.

Comment: The entire first block of code is irrelevant to your question. Just gives us `filesDataPairsListTesting` with dummy values. No one is going to install the `nltk` package just so they can run your example! Even if they would - again, the first part is not relevant, just remove it

Comment: Ah,  now i understand what you meant. I have removed the libraries and created an example of the needed data set rather than include the nltk library. I wrongly assumed that others might be using that one already.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just have nested lists. Just loop through both. E.g:

```
ls = [
    [
        ([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]),
        ([1, 2, 3], ["d", "e", "f"])
    ],
    [
        ([4, 5, 6], ["a", "b", "c"]),
        ([4, 5, 6], ["d", "e", "f"]),
        ([4, 5, 6], ["g", "h", "i"])
    ]
]

for pairs in ls:
    for pair in pairs:
        print(pair)
```